# Kotlin: Override interface method named 'getAuthorities()' with 'val authorities'

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin I’m implementing a Java interface that contains method:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

Now, of course I can just go ahead and override the method directly, but I’m wondering if there is a way to implement this with a Kotlin property, along the lines of:

```
/* Broken code, does not compile */
override val authorities = listOf( /* ... */ )
```

Or does Kotlin simply not support this kind of thing?

Comment: Not the last time I checked, but the method can still be used as if it were a property from Kotlin.

Comment: Though you can use `override val authorities:Collection = listOf( /* ... */ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot replace a method(Behavior), from an interface, with a property.

Its not possible to override JVM methods with Kotlin properties

Comment: Yeah, this is apparently a [deep rooted issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653) within language design. Thank you for answering.